# The Extended Participial Phrase

Tags: grammar-identification

> eine von allen echten Demokraten zu begrüßende
>   Entwicklung

Mostly "zu" comes with infinitive or as preposition.

Is the "zu" in the above phrase an adverb?

Answer (score 5):

The *zu* in *zu begrüßen* is a part of the infinitive, which is why it can be considered a (verbal) **affix**, even though it is visually seperated from the verb. Modal participle (gerundivum) constructions as in your example ultimately build upon this *zu* infinitive, preserving the affix, even though they turn the verb into an adjective (or something similar to an adjective, depending on your preferred grammarian gang).

If you think about it, the fact that the *zu* in your example stands alone to begin with is simply owing to your choice of verb. Compare: *die zu begrüßende Entwicklung / die abzulehnende Entwicklung*, where the status as an affix is more obvious.

Comment: "eine von allen echten Demokraten begrüßende Entwicklung" Is this sentence  grammatically correct without "zu"?

Comment: @ughitudhi No. The modal participle is a very special animal, which requires the _zu_ and has a distinct - passive - meaning. _Eine von allen echten Demokraten zu begrüßende Entwicklung_ is a development that the speaker expects to be welcomed by all real democrats. (A simple participle I construction on the other hand would have an active meaning: _Eine begrüßende Entwicklung_ is a development that welcomes, which arguably makes little sense.)

Answer (score 3):

All of the three non-finite forms can be used as adjectives.

> 1. **die Gäste begrüßen** ist ihre Aufgabe
>   2. die Entwicklung ist **zu begrüßen**
>   3. die Entwicklung wird **begrüßt**

And parallel:

> 1.' die die Gäste **begrüßende** Dame
>   2.' die **zu begrüßende** Entwicklung
>   3.' die **begrüßte** Entwicklung

It seems reasonable to assume that *zu* plays the same role in both cases. Since it can't be separated from the verb, *zu* and the infinitive should be considered as a single word that just happens to be spelled as two words (as johnl has pointed out).

Cases 2 and 3 have a passive meaning (*Entwicklung* is a [patient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient_(grammar)), i.e. the thing being welcomed); case 2 also has a modal meaning of obligation (or possibility). Think of the paraphrase:

> Die Entwicklung muß begrüßt werden.

Answer (score 2):

> eine von allen echten Demokraten zu begrüßende Entwicklung

means that all real democratic people *should* welcome this evolution.
The construction is like in English *X is to be done*.
The "zu" in the German sentence has a similar function as the "to" in the English one.